# How to create fragment after receiving intent from activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-asynctask

I receive an array list of cholesterol monitors in the onCreate method of an activity.I'm trying to pass it into the fragment in onPostExecute but currently it passes in a null list? **In my onCreate.**

```
cholesterol_monitor= this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("monitorList");
        CholesterolFragment cholesterolFragment= new CholesterolFragment();
        cholesterolFragment.execute(cholesterol_monitor);
```

In my AsyncTask methods

```
 private class CholesterolFragment extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>, Void, ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>> {


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> doInBackground(ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>... arrayLists) {
            cholesterol_monitor=arrayLists[0];
            return cholesterol_monitor;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> result){
            cholesterol_monitor= result;
            monitorListFragment = MonitorListFragment.newInstance(cholesterol_monitor);
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_monitor_layout, monitorListFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:In my monitorListFragment

```
 public static MonitorListFragment newInstance(ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> monitor_list) {
        MonitorListFragment fragment = new MonitorListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_MONITOR_LIST, monitor_list);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

EDIT: Its because there are null objects in my list so I added a check in my monitor list recycler adapter but no names are displayed?

This is in my monitorlistrecyclerAdapter

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final MonitorListRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!(data.get(position).getPatient()== null)){
       String patient = "Patient: " + data.get(position).getPatient().getName().get(0).getNameAsSingleString();
       String  cholesterolLevel = "Cholesterol: "
            + String.format("%.2f", data.get(position).getPatientCholesterolLevel()) + " "
            + data.get(position).getUnitsMeasurement();
        holder.patientNameView.setText(patient);
        holder.cholesterolView.setText(cholesterolLevel);


    }
```

Comment: share your MonitorListFragment code

Comment: Updated with the monitor list fragment code

Comment: So, is this, `this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("monitorList");`, returning null?

Comment: Make sure you are using correct key to fetch value  from intent and access value from getArgumemts().getParcelableArrayList("key"). If you taking same step let me know

Comment: @PPartisan No it is returning an array list of cholesterol monitors as expected.But when I put it into the fragment I get a null pointer exception. I thought it was because I created the fragment in onCreate so it might create the fragment before I got the array list.So I used onPostexecute but doesn't seem like it works

Comment: @Ankit I used the correct key as the array list is not null but when I pass it into the fragments it says null object.

Comment: Do you get a `NullPointerException` crash/stacktrace? If so then please add it to your question. Also, your `AsyncTask` is unnecessary, you could simplify your code by removing it.

Comment: Updated the code. It works when I create the fragments in the same activity. However I tried creating the fragments in a separate activity by passing an intent and it crashes with nullpointerException

Comment: Ok - so your `List` isn't null, but the entry at a certain position is null.

Comment: Your list item is empty. Add check whether obj is empty, set default value for clarification

Comment: @PPartisan I've added a check but its still null?

Comment: @Ankit I've added the code to check whether obj is empty but its still null

Comment: We are not sure with value but we here tracking cause of crash. If it's not happening, then we are on right page. For NULL values, contact server team or apply filter for this

Comment: I'm just not sure why this doesn't happen if I try to create the fragment in the same activity.I added the method to check if its not null now the activity can start but the names are not displayed.This means all values in it are null.

Comment: Is CholesterolMonitor Parcelable? Really I think you just need to debug this - use a debugger or print statements and step through your code. Find out exactly where the output differs from what you expect,try and solve it, and if you can't, post a new question. That will help get you answers

Comment: @SookLim yes, values from service is null or your key is incorrect. TRY TO ADD DEFAULT VALUE IN PERSON AND CHECK IS THEIR CODING ISSUE OR SERVICE DATA ISSUE

Answer (score 0):

How is it if you first pass data to the fragment

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList(key,value);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then retrieve in the fragment

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
  // execute AsyncTask class  
}
```

Comment: How do I retrieve in the fragment that is created?

Comment: first make `CholesterolFragment extends Fragment` then create subclass(nested classes) who's extending `AsyncTask<ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>, Void, ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>>`